# TypeError: unsupported operand type when attempted to subtract values in one pandas dataframe column from another

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, typeerror

I'm trying to write a function which does the following:

1. Finds the average of a pandas column.
2. Places this value in a new column.
3. Finds the month average (i.e. the average value of all Februaries combined)
4. Subtracts month average from the annual average and places this value in a new column (month effect).
5. Adds values from 'month effect' column to an existing column containing modelled predictions.

The `DataFrame` is indexed by `datetime`. The code below throws up a `TypeError:unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'instancemethod' and 'float'` but I'm not sure why. The trace is below the code. Could somebody suggest a fix?

```
def get_RIM2(df,obs, rim):
    """df, observation, modelled value"""
    a= obs.mean #mean of whole dataset
    b= obs.median #median of whole dataset
    df.insert(len(df.columns), 'Mean', a)
    df.insert(len(df.columns), 'Median', b)
    g = obs.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('M'))
    h = obs.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('M'))
    g.transform('mean') # mean for each month
    h.transform('median') # median for each month
    df['Mmean'] = df['Mean'] - g.transform('mean') # month effect
    df['Mmedian'] = df['Median'] - h.transform('median') # month effect
    df['RIMs2a'] = rim + df['Mmean']
    df['RIMs2b'] = rim + df['Mmedian']
    return df

get_RIM2(sve_DOC, sve_DOC['DOC_mg/L'], sve_DOC['RIMsDOC'])
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-249d56b28c7a> in <module>()
     14     return df
     15 
---> 16 get_RIM2(sve_DOC, sve_DOC['DOC_mg/L'], sve_DOC['RIMsDOC'])
     17 get_RIM2(svv_DOC, svv_DOC['DOC_mg/L'], svv_DOC['RIMsDOC'])
     18 get_RIM2(svw_DOC, svw_DOC['DOC_mg/L'], svw_DOC['RIMsDOC'])

<ipython-input-69-249d56b28c7a> in get_RIM2(df, obs, rim)
      8     g.transform('mean') # mean for each month
      9     h.transform('median') # median for each month
---> 10     df['Mmean'] = df['Mean'] - g.transform('mean')
     11     df['Mmedian'] = df['Median'] - h.transform('median')
     12     df['RIMs2a'] = rim + df['Mmean']

C:\Users\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.pyc in wrapper(left, right, name)
    495                     rvalues = com.take_1d(rvalues, ridx)
    496 
--> 497             arr = na_op(lvalues, rvalues)
    498 
    499             return left._constructor(wrap_results(arr), index=index,

C:\Users\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.pyc in na_op(x, y)
    449                 result = np.empty(x.size, dtype=dtype)
    450                 mask = notnull(x) & notnull(y)
--> 451                 result[mask] = op(x[mask], y[mask])
    452             else:
    453                 result = pa.empty(len(x), dtype=x.dtype)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'instancemethod' and 'float'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need parentheses after your initial mean/median calls (as below) - otherwise you are assigning the function to DataFrame, not the value it returns

```
a= obs.mean() #mean of whole dataset
b= obs.median() #median of whole dataset
```